# Want to call a method of a fragment from other fragment in android 2.2

Tags: android, methods, android-fragments

I have 2 Fragments for a activity.
e.g. FragmentA and FragmentB
I have a public method funA in FragmentA
Now I want call funA from FragmentB of FragmentA.

I have replaced FragmentA with FragmentB.
I am using support libs as I am making application on Android 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a good idea, because you are coupling the fragments; FragmentB should not know about methods from FragmentA, or vice versa.

A better solution is described in section "Creating event callbacks to the activity" here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will definitely try the link you have provided. My problem is that I have a normal fragment which shows information of the overlay market on a mapfragment. So now I want that when I press a button on the infofragment It should take me to the overlay market location. So for this I have created a public method in mapfragment which I plan to call from infofragment.